# Why doesn't make produce a .o file?

Tags: makefile, clang, gnu-make

I'm learning Makefile and I can't seem to figure out why this rule is producing an executable with no extension instead of a `.o` file.

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS=-c

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) %.c
```

I've tried going through the [GNU make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), but that didn't help either.

I tried using other Automatic Variables but that didn't work either.

```
CC = clang

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $< -c
```

This doesn't work either, everything I've tried produces an executable with no extension.

```
CC = clang

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) %.c -o %.o
```

I need the rule to work like this:

Suppose I want to compile `c_filename.c`:

```
$ make c_filename
```

The resulting file should be `c_filename.o`

Comment: You need to use automatic variables to substitute both .o and .c files: `%.o: %.c` `gcc -c -o $@ $<` Called like `make c_filename.o`

Comment: thanks @VLL that rule seemed to work

Comment: Your `Makefile` tells `make` what to do if you ask it to produce an `.o` file, but you are not asking for that, so it is using its built-in rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So make has a [bunch of implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) that are supposed to make things easier. You can turn them off by adding this line:

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

If you want it to make `c_filename.o` you can call `make c_filename.o`. When you call it without the suffix, it assumes you want the executable, which is handled by an implicit rule (unless you disable them as above). Generally, if what you want is the object files, you'd add an `all` target like this:

```
all: c_filename.o
```

That will then make the object file whenever you run make without any arguments. If you want to specify the rule to build the executable, you might use something like this:

```
%: %.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Then you could have make create the executable and object files like this:

```
all: c_filename.o c_filename
```